# Android-studio doesn't launch

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-18.04

I've been following these [instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-Linux) to install Android-studio.
With exception I used

> sudo snap install android-studio --classic

instead of

> sudo snap install android-studio

And now when I try to launch it

> android-studio

I get the next message

> /var not root-owned 1000:1000

What should I do? Did I messed something up? What can I do to launch it?

P.S. Trying to launch it from Ubuntu Software does nothing.

Comment: Don't use snap, follow the official installation instruction at https://developer.android.com/studio/install?

Comment: Don't go with unofficial packages. You may end up scrapping Ubuntu OS if unofficial packages contain harmful or incompatible code. Please refer the official guide for installing Android Studio on Linux based systems https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux